# How add a custom field to create page form

Tags: customization, custom-fields, phpfox

I'm looking to add a select list field named experience with fixed set of static options to the 'create page form' in pages module but i'm unable to find any help, i want to display it on the second step of page creation. I'm using phpFox Version 3.4.1 with mysql. Any help will be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can add any select field on add.html.php controller in 
module/pages/template/default/add.html.php